# How do I add a reference to my Model(s) to a unit test project for MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Background: learning about MVC, Bootstrap, etc. So, new to doing this in Visual Studio. More of a C# backend programmer / hand-rolled html/css/js fiddler.

I'm trying to add a unit test to an MVC project, and I get the uselessly generic "A reference to 'Your Project Name' could not be added." error when I try to reference my main project so I can test against my Model classes.

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- Created new Project with File -> New Project -> Templates -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application
- Selected "Web Application" from ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates
- Added some code, including a class to serve as a model for Code First.
- Added a Unit Test project under the Solution folder by right-clicking and choosing Add -> New Project, under the Visual C# folder for the templates I picked Test -> Unit Test Project. The targeted framework at the top was set to .NET Framework 4.5.2

Googling around suggested that I had a target framework mismatch. I don't know how to check the target framework on a MVC project I guess, the Project Properties window lists Application and Solution DNX SDK version ( set to 1.0.0-beta5, platform .NET Framework ) but doesn't tell me what framework I'm targeting.

How I can utilize Microsoft's unit testing framework with this kind of project?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the Package Manager Console (**TOOLS > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console**) and type the following command:

> Update-Package

This will update and 'level' all packages of both projects and any version mismatch should be fixed.